# MySQL Finding the Last Business Day

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has all holidays/weekend days listed. Is there a query that could help me find the last business day (not holiday or weekend) that has occurred?

Example: If it is Sunday, I want the date of last Friday. Assuming Friday is not a holiday.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f474e4

Here is the structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar_table` (
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `y` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dw` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthName` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dayName` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `w` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isWeekday` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isHoliday` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `holidayDescr` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tradingHoliday` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dt`)
)
```

Comment: I already have something like this.  But I need to find the very last business day that has occurred.

Comment: What is the table structure? how can we helps you if we don't know which columns tell us what.

Comment: `Assuming Friday is not a holiday` Are you aware that it is country dependent?

Comment: Please show us your table structure.

Comment: I have attached the SQL Fiddle for my table structure.  And no, I did not think about country dependency.

Comment: The All but the first column and the last 3 columns appear to be entirely redundant

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT max(dt) 
FROM calendar_table
where dt <= curdate()
and isHoliday = 0
and isWeekDay = 1;
```

You'll maybe have to adjust it a little bit, since you haven't posted what each of your column stores.

But that the basic, to select the max date where all the indications tells it a working date within the range before today.

Comment: I suspect isWeekDay = 1, but yes, that should do it.